# How to get $id from url parameter in Laminas?

Tags: php, zend-framework, laminas

if i have url like: http://localhost/customer/view/7

```
'route' => '/customer[/:action[/:id]]'
```

I want to get 7 as `$id` for my `editAction()` but i cant use

```
$id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id' , '0');
```

So how can i get it? Thank you

Comment: Can you paste a content of full `router` definition? `fromRoute` is a correct method to use.

Comment: Hi @divix this is full router definition

'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'customer' => [
                'type' => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/customer[/:action[/:id]]',
                    'constraints' => [
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ],
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\CustomerController::class,
                        'action' => 'signIn',

Comment: Nevermind i found the way :)) thank you so much! have a good day @divix

Comment: Can you at least paste a solution to your problem?

Comment: i pasted my solution :)) pls take a look

Answer (score 1):

The solution is change the view.phtml

**Before**:

```
<a href="<?= $this->url('customer', ['action' => 'edit']) ?>">
```

**After**:

```
<a href="<?= $this->url('customer', ['action' => 'edit', 'id' => $customer->id]) ?>">
```

With that `id` you can use: `$id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id' , '0');` in `editAction()`